FastReport. Two Headers
How can the table output be implemented. which has one headline for the first time and another on all subsequent pages?
Example:
Page1 - HEADER 1
        TABLE RECORDS 1-100
Page2 - HEADER 2
        TABLE RECORDS 101-200
PageN - HEADER 2
        TABLE RECORDS N101-N200

I suggested choosing a child element for the header
Header3.Visible:= <Page#> <= 2;    
child1.visible := <Page#> > 2;


Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Yes, having a child band is the way. You can set different visibility for the parent and child header bands. There are two ways to do it.

Set the Visible property with the code
Set a condition value for VisibleExpression using the designer's UI.

